# *Solve* How to align the close button in bootstrap popup modal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple bootstrap popup modal. Right now when the popup appear, the close x button is at center and I want to align the close button x to the right corner of the popup window. How can I do this?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="checkNameSurvey-modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="loginmodal-container" id="checkNameSurveymodal-container">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h4 style="text-align:center"></h4><br>
            <div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control login-input" id="newSurveyName" onkeyup="if(event.keyCode==13)document.getElementById('checkName-button').click()">

                <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="checkName-button"></button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the close x button being "placed at the center".  It appears to be in the top right corner to me: http://www.bootply.com/G1dhDkQyYU

Comment: applying `display: inline-block; text-align-right;` to it should work, but if this were to be placed in a jsfiddle I could test other things :)

Comment: I'm unable to replicate your issue. [I used this fiddle to test it.](https://jsfiddle.net/4castle/jmocnfus/2/) The close button looks like it's already in the top-right corner.

Comment: I had similar issue, but it turns out that it's a bug (v4.0.0-apha.4). Seems fixed v4.0.0-alpha.6, but it has other issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using 'modal-header', 'modal-content' classes. Go through [UI DIALOGS](http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/admin_1/ui_modals.html)

here inspect element in the modal.

Comment: Include example markup in your answer, It would be more helpful than linking to a theme demo site.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `float:right`. That might shift the cross button to the right side.

Sharing a screenshot of the modal box would have been more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I found a mistake, the close x button is align at the center because I put it inside of my class "loginmodal-container" which I have a stylesheet of center. So I fix that problem. Thank you